# XML to SQL - Rows that have columns without distinct identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

What would be the correct, most efficient way of importing/converting this kind of XML into an SQL database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data app-version-major="xyz" app-version-minor="xyz" app-version-build="xyz" schema-version="xyz" export-time="xyz" db-product-name="Apache Derby" db-product-version="xyz">
<table name="table1" entire="Y">
    <columns>
        <column name="col1" class="java.lang.Long" type-id="-5" db-type="bigint"/>
        <column name="col2" class="java.lang.String" length="10" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col3" class="java.lang.String" length="255" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col4" class="java.lang.Double" type-id="8" db-type="double"/>
        <column name="col5" class="java.lang.String" length="1" type-id="1" db-type="char"/>
        <column name="col6" class="java.lang.Double" type-id="8" db-type="double"/>
        <column name="col7" class="java.lang.String" length="50" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col8" class="java.lang.String" length="1" type-id="1" db-type="char"/>
        <column name="col9" class="java.lang.String" length="2000" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col11" class="java.lang.String" length="1" type-id="1" db-type="char"/>
        <column name="col12" class="java.sql.Timestamp" type-id="93" db-type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="col13" class="java.sql.Timestamp" type-id="93" db-type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="col14" class="java.lang.String" length="50" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col15" class="java.sql.Timestamp" type-id="93" db-type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="col16" class="java.lang.String" length="50" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col17" class="java.lang.Long" type-id="-5" db-type="bigint"/>
        <column name="col18" class="java.lang.String" length="255" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col19" class="java.lang.String" length="255" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col20" class="java.lang.String" length="255" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col21" class="java.lang.String" length="1" type-id="1" db-type="char"/>
        <column name="col22" class="java.sql.Timestamp" type-id="93" db-type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="col23" class="java.lang.String" length="20" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col24" class="java.lang.String" length="20" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col25" class="java.lang.String" length="50" type-id="12" db-type="varchar"/>
        <column name="col26" class="java.lang.Long" type-id="-5" db-type="bigint"/>
    </columns>
    <row>
        <v>value1</v>
        <v>value2</v>
        <v>value3</v>
        <v>value4</v>
        <v>value5</v>
        <v>value6</v>
        <v>value7</v>
        <v>value8</v>
        <v>value9</v>
        <v>value10</v>
        <v>value11</v>
        <v>value12</v>
        <v>value13</v>
        <v>value14</v>
        <v>value15</v>
        <v>value16</v>
        <v>value17</v>
        <v>value18</v>
        <v>value19</v>
        <v>value20</v>
        <v>value21</v>
        <v>value22</v>
        <v>value23</v>
        <v>value24</v>
        <v>value25</v>
    </row>
    <row>
        <v>value1</v>
        <v>value2</v>
        <v>value3</v>
        <v>value4</v>
        <v>value5</v>
        <v>value6</v>
        <v>value7</v>
        <v>value8</v>
        <v>value9</v>
        <v>value10</v>
        <v>value11</v>
        <v>value12</v>
        <v>value13</v>
        <v>value14</v>
        <v>value15</v>
        <v>value16</v>
        <v>value17</v>
        <v>value18</v>
        <v>value19</v>
        <v>value20</v>
        <v>value21</v>
        <v>value22</v>
        <v>value23</v>
        <v>value24</v>
        <v>value25</v>
    </row>
</table>
```

Current experiments have been on SQL Express, trying to find a way to get the information inside `<row>` tags to correct columns (row1->col1->value1, etc).

I've tried following this guide: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/ - but I'm stuck selecting the "anonymous" column data inside rows - all I get is Null.

I've also tried to run a few XML to CSV converters with no luck. What would be the way to go with this?

Comment: Is the structure always the same or do have to handle different XML data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML is always the same in structure I'd do it like this:

In my example I assumed, that the XML is read into a XML variable already. If you need help how to read XML from file into SQL, just ask...

Just paste this in an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @XML XML=
'<data app-version-major="xyz" app-version-minor="xyz" app-version-build="xyz" schema-version="xyz" export-time="xyz" db-product-name="Apache Derby" db-product-version="xyz">
  <table name="table1" entire="Y">
    <columns>
      <column name="col1" class="java.lang.Long" type-id="-5" db-type="bigint" />
      <column name="col2" class="java.lang.String" length="10" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col3" class="java.lang.String" length="255" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col4" class="java.lang.Double" type-id="8" db-type="double" />
      <column name="col5" class="java.lang.String" length="1" type-id="1" db-type="char" />
      <column name="col6" class="java.lang.Double" type-id="8" db-type="double" />
      <column name="col7" class="java.lang.String" length="50" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col8" class="java.lang.String" length="1" type-id="1" db-type="char" />
      <column name="col9" class="java.lang.String" length="2000" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col11" class="java.lang.String" length="1" type-id="1" db-type="char" />
      <column name="col12" class="java.sql.Timestamp" type-id="93" db-type="timestamp" />
      <column name="col13" class="java.sql.Timestamp" type-id="93" db-type="timestamp" />
      <column name="col14" class="java.lang.String" length="50" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col15" class="java.sql.Timestamp" type-id="93" db-type="timestamp" />
      <column name="col16" class="java.lang.String" length="50" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col17" class="java.lang.Long" type-id="-5" db-type="bigint" />
      <column name="col18" class="java.lang.String" length="255" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col19" class="java.lang.String" length="255" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col20" class="java.lang.String" length="255" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col21" class="java.lang.String" length="1" type-id="1" db-type="char" />
      <column name="col22" class="java.sql.Timestamp" type-id="93" db-type="timestamp" />
      <column name="col23" class="java.lang.String" length="20" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col24" class="java.lang.String" length="20" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col25" class="java.lang.String" length="50" type-id="12" db-type="varchar" />
      <column name="col26" class="java.lang.Long" type-id="-5" db-type="bigint" />
    </columns>
    <row>
      <v>value1</v>
      <v>value2</v>
      <v>value3</v>
      <v>value4</v>
      <v>value5</v>
      <v>value6</v>
      <v>value7</v>
      <v>value8</v>
      <v>value9</v>
      <v>value10</v>
      <v>value11</v>
      <v>value12</v>
      <v>value13</v>
      <v>value14</v>
      <v>value15</v>
      <v>value16</v>
      <v>value17</v>
      <v>value18</v>
      <v>value19</v>
      <v>value20</v>
      <v>value21</v>
      <v>value22</v>
      <v>value23</v>
      <v>value24</v>
      <v>value25</v>
    </row>
    <row>
      <v>value1</v>
      <v>value2</v>
      <v>value3</v>
      <v>value4</v>
      <v>value5</v>
      <v>value6</v>
      <v>value7</v>
      <v>value8</v>
      <v>value9</v>
      <v>value10</v>
      <v>value11</v>
      <v>value12</v>
      <v>value13</v>
      <v>value14</v>
      <v>value15</v>
      <v>value16</v>
      <v>value17</v>
      <v>value18</v>
      <v>value19</v>
      <v>value20</v>
      <v>value21</v>
      <v>value22</v>
      <v>value23</v>
      <v>value24</v>
      <v>value25</v>
    </row>
  </table>
</data>';

SELECT @XML.value('/data[1]/@app-version-major','varchar(max)') AS AppVersionMajor
      ,@XML.value('/data[1]/@app-version-minor','varchar(max)') AS AppVersionMinor 
      --further attribs of node "data"
      ,@XML.value('(/data/table)[1]/@name','varchar(max)') AS TableName 
      ,@XML.value('(/data/table)[1]/@entire','varchar(max)') AS TableEntire

      ,One.Row.value('v[1]','varchar(max)') AS col1 --use the fitting name and type of your "table" node here
      ,One.Row.value('v[2]','varchar(max)') AS col2
      ,One.Row.value('v[3]','varchar(max)') AS col3
      --further columns here

FROM @XML.nodes('/data/table/row') AS One(Row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of your xml is that you could have 5, 10 or 100 values by row. Same process can apply.

Use a xml parser (java, or for other languages), and iterate

for each row, inject with SQL.

It is rather efficient, even for thousands of data.